# Type 'UserStore' is not defined

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm following [this](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project) tutorial for incorporating OWIN authentication into a webforms app.

On these two lines:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
```

which translate in VB to:

```
Dim userStore = New UserStore(Of IdentityUser)()
Dim userManager = New UserManager(Of IdentityUser)(userStore)
```

I see an immediate exception:

> "Type 'UserStore' is not defined"

At the top of my page I have

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
```

The tutorial also has

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
```

but this also generates an error (which might be the underlying cause):

> Namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework [sic] cannot be found

I wondered if the tutorial is now out of date considering that Identity 2 has just been released.  Can anyone suggest any solutions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It emerges that the NuGet packages were not installed correctly.  Searching for and reinstalling the following packages fixed the problem:

1. Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
2. Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity.Owin
3. Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb